# Problem in repeated values into dictionaries for each iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-requests

The code below is run without an error, but there are repeated values for each iteration of the for-loop. I tried to fix this error, but I can't. I need really to your help.

```
import requests, json

conditions = []

list1 = []

list2 = []

playlist= []


for line in lines:

    if '<A HREF="/1920' in line:
        parts = line.split("\"")
        url = base + parts[1]
        #print(url)
        r = requests.get(url)
        teamlines = r.text.split("\n")
        parse = False
        parse1 = False
        tn =0
        rc = 0
        cc = 0   
        aa=0
        bb=0
        d ={}

        for teamline in teamlines:

          if '<table width="856" border=1 cellpadding=1 cellspacing=1 class="chssmallreg">' in teamline:
                tn+=1
          if '<tr valign=top align=right>' in teamline:
                rc +=1
                cc = 0
          if '<td ' in teamline:
                cc+=1

          if cc == 0 and tn == 1 and '</td>' in teamline:

                if '<td>&nbsp;</td>' != teamline:

                    playernumber = teamline.split('<td>')[1].split('</td>')[0]
                    list1.append(playernumber)
                    players = {}
                    players['player number'] = playernumber

         if tn == 1 and cc ==1:
                if '<td colspan=3 align=left>Bench</td>' != teamline:
                    playername = teamline.split('<td align=left><strong>')[1].split('</strong></td>')[0]
                    list2.append(playername)
                    players['player name']= playername
                    playlist.append(players)

                if '<FONT SIZE=+1 FACE="Verdana,Arial,Helvetica"><B><I>&nbsp;' in teamline:
                   team_name =  teamline.split('<FONT SIZE=+1 FACE="Verdana,Arial,Helvetica"><B> 
                   <I>&nbsp;')[1].split('(Men)<BR>')[0]

                if '<td valign=top bgcolor="#DDDDDD"><strong>Home:</strong></td>' in teamline:
                   parse1= True                 

                if '<td valign=top bgcolor="#DDDDDD"><strong>Away:</strong></td>' in teamline:
                   parse1= False

                if '<td valign=top bgcolor="#DDDDDD">' in teamline and parse1==True:
                   aa+=1
                if '</td>' in teamline and parse1==True:   
                   bb+=1
if parse1:

                   if '<td valign=top bgcolor="#DDDDDD"> ' in teamline:
                       Situational_Records_Conference = teamline.split('<td valign=top 
                       bgcolor="#DDDDDD">')[1].split('</td>')[0] 

                       Situational_Records_Conference = Situational_Records_Conference.split('-')
                       d['team'] = {}
                       d['team']['team name'] = team_name
                       d['team']['team wins'] = Situational_Records_Conference [0]
                       d['team']['team losses'] = Situational_Records_Conference [1]
                       d['team']['team ties'] = Situational_Records_Conference [2]   
                       d['team']['team players'] = playlist



                       conditions.append(d)

print(json.dumps(conditions))
```

Comment: What's the right indent of `if parse1:`?

Comment: it is under "if '</td>' in teamline and parse1==True"

Comment: After the first iteration of the for-loop, the list called "conditions" contains the right values, but after the first iteration of the for-loop, there are iterations of the values and I don't know where is the problem